# maplist with parametrized predicate

Tags: list, prolog, meta-predicate

Is it possible to use parametrized predicate in `mapList`?

For example,  I would like to do following:
iter by list, and for each even element (list contains only numbers) map this element to some value (this value is set by parameter of predicate).

Sample queries:

```
?- mapList(p(red, blue), [1,2,3,4], [red, blue, red, blue]).
true.

?- mapList(p(green, blue), [1,2,3,4], [green, blue, green, blue]).
true.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the predicate just get all additional parameters. After defining p/4, running your queries (once mapList has been corrected to maplist):

```
?- [user].
p(C1,C2,N,C) :- 0 =:= N mod 2 -> C = C2 ; C = C1.
(^D here)

?- maplist(p(red, blue), [1,2,3,4], L).
L = [red, blue, red, blue].
```

Comment: @HaskellFun and more fundamentally, in Prolog, the `call` predicate (used implicitly in `maplist`) knows how to manage the arguments. So if you have `sum(X, Y, Z) :- Z is X + Y.` and you queried, `call(sum(2), 3, Z).` you would get `Z = 5`.

Comment: Like partial feeding functions in functional languages!